# Binary Tree first incomplete

Tags: php, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I've the following Binary Tree:

```
            [Node1]
    [Node2]        [Node3]
[Node4][Node5] [Node6][Node7]
     [...]          [...]
```

each node has it's unique id and node are stored separately holding a 'parent' parameter.

what I need is get the first 'parent' that is incomplete (ie that node without 2 child nodes); with "first 'parent'" I mean the most closest to the root node.

I've tried some loops but always get the same result only loop one side...

Update:

This is infinity, I think not sure it is DFS

Comment: Insufficient - please define how nodes are ordered ...  perhaps DFS, or BFS, or inverted ...

Comment: DepthFirstSearch would search in the order: 1,2,4,5,3,6,7 _______  BreadthFirstSearch would search in order:    1,2,3,4,5,6,7.  Try google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the shallowest node in a tree meeting a condition, you will want to use [breadth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

It basically looks something like this, as a fragment, in a language-agnostic way

```
q = empty queue
q.push(root)

while q is not empty
    current = q.pop
    if current meets condition
        return current
    for each child of current
        q.push(child)
```

That should be implementable in any language, ensure that q is actually a FIFO queue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the desired result with combination of these two functions:

```
function traverseTree( $id, $level=0 ) {
    static $depths = array();

    $depth++;

    $c = get_comments( array( 'type' => 'member', 'parent' => $id ) );

    if( count( $c ) < 2 ) {
        $depths[$id] = $level;
    }

    if( isset( $c[0] ) )
        traverseTree( $c[0]->comment_ID, $level+1 );

    if( isset( $c[1] ) )
        traverseTree( $c[1]->comment_ID, $level+1 );

    return $depths;
}

function depthChoose( $depths ) {
    return min( array_keys( $depths, min( $depths ) ) );
}
```

So `depthChoose( traverseTree( $id ) );` does the work.

Note: $c[0] as same as node->left and $c[1] as node->right;